# Question on a type of interrogation involving comme

Tags: grammaire, adverbes, interrogative

In the book *Exercices de grammaire en contexte, niveau intermédiare*, there is a question involving two types of interrogatives with comme:

> Qu'est-ce que ... comme, quoi comme....

The authors give two examples, under the statement: Demander une précision, as follows:

> J'ai une voiture - Tu as **quoi comme** voiture (familier)
>
> Il cherche un appartement - **Qu'est-ce qu'il** cherche **comme** appartement?
> (courant)

My question is:

1- What does *Qu'est-ce que ... comme, quoi comme* mean? Does that mean What kind? (as in the example: What type of car do you have? What kind of flat is he looking for?)

2- If they have the same meaning, is *quoi comme* used in informal way, and *qu'est-ce que...comme* used in formal way?

I have searched in all my grammar textbook but I haven't found anything that relates to these type of interrogation.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, they both mean kind of or type of or sort of. I have a question: why are you asking questions about French in English, which is not your mother tongue? Won't that be even more confusing??

Comment: Hi, I'm not English native but French grammar textbook written in English (and of course French) is far more better than the ones that written in my native language. So I have no other choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, both mean "what kind of" and are interchangeable:

> Tu as quoi comme voiture ? (familier)
>
> Qu'est-ce que tu as comme voiture ? (courant)

or

> Qu'est-ce qu'il cherche comme appartement ? (courant)
>
> Il cherche quoi comme appartement ? (familier)

The reason why one expression is a bit more formal than the other is not about *quoi comme* vs *qu'est-ce que... comme* but about the construction of the sentence. Questions beginning like an affirmation (*Tu as...*) are less formal than questions beginning with *qu'est-ce-que*.

> **Formal**: Que recherches-tu comme appartement ?
>
> **Less formal**: Qu'est-ce que tu (re)cherches comme appartement ?
>
> **Informal**: Tu (re)cherches quoi comme appartement ?

Comment: Both are basically interchangeable. Tu cherches quoi comme appartement? means the same thing exactly as: Qu'est-ce que tu cherches comme appartement. More formal overall would also be: Quel genre d'appartement cherchez-vous?